# How do I make a Script that (when open) runs cmd and outputs something I wrote?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python.

I wanted to make a Python File (script) that would run `cmd` and then run a Command for example: `net user`. I tried this

```
import os
os.system ('start cmd')
```

but I still need help.

Comment: Be sure to check your question before posting.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: What did you see when you tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to open a command prompt and make *that* command prompt run a command or do you want to just run a program?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the guideline before asking your question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes I want to open a command prompt and make that command prompt run a command  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess
import sys

command = "net user"
subprocess.call(command,shell=True,stdout=sys.stdout)
```

Example output:

```
User accounts for \\COMPUTER

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user1                    user2                    user3                 
The command completed successfully.
```